# Python3.6, trying to append to a attribute list during recursive backtracking, but it discards results?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, backtracking

I am trying to generate all unique subsets using recursive backtracking. ( interview prep ).
The problem statement is: Given a set of distinct integers, nums, return all possible subsets (the power set). Note: The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets.

Though, for the input [1,2,3] my output for this is:

`[[],[],[1],[1,2],[1],[],[2],[]]`

When the answer should be:

`[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]`

Though, when I print out what I am appending to my list it prints the correct answers:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[3]
```

I thought that it could be an issue with passing these lists recursively, reusing them etc so I made copies of the params. For some reason I have to run a copy on my parameters as well.

Am i missing an understanding of the memory management of these data structures? I have been having the same issue when taking this approach for other backtracking problems.

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subset = [[]]

    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        self.initSubsets(nums,[])
        return self.subset

    def initSubsets(self,options,currentSubset):
        frameOptions = options.copy()
        frameCurrentSubset = currentSubset.copy()

        for option in options:
            # add option to subset
            frameCurrentSubset.append(option)
            # add to solution
            self.subset.append(frameCurrentSubset)
            print(frameCurrentSubset)
            # guarentee no dups
            frameOptions.remove(option)
            # recurse
            self.initSubsets(frameOptions,frameCurrentSubset)
            # undo changes
            frameCurrentSubset.remove(option)

        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is at this line:

```py
self.subset.append(frameCurrentSubset)
```

where you append a list to a list but later you

```py
frameCurrentSubset.remove(option)
```

where you remove an element from `frameCurrentSubset`. But the problem is by doing that you also remove that element from the list you have copied to `self.subset` because it's the same list in memory.

The solution is to use instead:

```py
self.subset.append(frameCurrentSubset[:])
```

which will append a new list that contains all the elements of `frameCurrentSubset` at that moment.

A complete solution is:

```py
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subset = [[]]

    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        self.initSubsets(nums,[])
        return self.subset

    def initSubsets(self,options,currentSubset):
        frameOptions = options.copy()
        frameCurrentSubset = currentSubset.copy()

        for option in options:
            # add option to subset
            frameCurrentSubset.append(option)
            # add to solution
            self.subset.append(frameCurrentSubset[:])
            print(frameCurrentSubset)
            # guarentee no dups
            frameOptions.remove(option)
            # recurse
            self.initSubsets(frameOptions,frameCurrentSubset)
            # undo changes
            frameCurrentSubset.remove(option)

        return

example = Solution()
result = example.subsets([1, 2, 3])
print(result)
```

Comment: So is it actually passing it by reference and not by value?

Comment: A list contains references not values (because everything is an object in Python).